# how to decode jwt token in Node.js which is generated in java?

Tags: java, node.js, jwt

I'm trying to decode the JWT in node server [npm install jsonwebtoken] which is created in java [io.jsonwebtoken / jjwt / 0.6.0] but getting invalid signature error.

Does anyone had experienced the same and found the solution then could you please share with the group.

## in JAVA

jwtToken = Jwts.builder().setSubject(email).claim("roles", "user").setIssuedAt(new Date(currentTimeInMills)).setExpiration(new Date(expireIn))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256,"secretKey").compact();

## in node

var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var decoded = jwt.verify(jwtToken, "secretKey");

Answer (score 0):

Is your node code defaulting to HS256 for the SignatureAlgorithm?

The error is quite clear and JWT is famously cross-platform compatible.

Verify the keys are identical on both sides, the claim objects are identical on both sides, and that the signature algorithms used are identical on both sides.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am able to decode the token in node after using com.auth0.java-jwt.3.2.0 jar in java and var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'); in node.

Comment: So did you switch Java libraries then? The other way to test this I just realized is to use an online utility to decode and use java to encode and vice versa. That will allow you to either independently test the encode/decode of either node or java and then when you know both sides work independently you know they'll work together.

I've had issues with some implementations of JWT in Java that just don't play nice with other platforms. That might've been the case in your instance here as well.